# My object is moving out of place during a Cloth Simulation. what can be a problem?

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

I want to make a flag moving by wind. I have subdivided a plane then pressed on cloth physics, in edit mode it works normally but when I change it in object mode the plane jumps down. I tried many thing but it still do the same, what can be a problem?

[image]

in this screenshot I'm in edit mode but, in object mode effects on the mesh weariedly.

[image]

As you see the plane is down below...

---

Answer (score 1):

By default, simulations like cloth start at frame 1 and end at 250, that is equal to the default timeline start and end, but they are not the same values, they can (and should) be different.

As you are working on frame 76, in object mode the simulation calculates where the flag should be after 75 frames, and gravity sends it under the ground.

To solve change the frames values in the cache section of the cloth simulator, and/or add a pin group to pin the flag to the pole.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Josh I solved this problem by myself exactly after posting this topic, but I have another question if you can help me? in a new project I tried to make simple cloth simulation, I covered the cloth on the cube,  by pressing play it works normally in object mode, but when I press edit mode the plane stands in the starting position, the vertices should appear on the covered position where the timeline cursor is stopped. maybe I accidently changed something but can't find what exactly, because it worked properly before and now it has changed.
as I see I can's add photos in the comment

Comment: @Sophia The _Edit Mode_ is there to edit the inherent base mesh of the object. It will not change when you simulate the cloth, since the simulation is a "virtual" deformation of the mesh, it just takes the base mesh which you see in _Edit Mode_ and tells the vertices where they should appear to be. Only after applying a cloth sim the mesh will be deformed for real - in the state of the frame on which you apply the cloth modifier, it will no longer be animated but the mesh is now permanently deformed, even in _Edit Mode_.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot Gordon, I get all the info that you provided me, now everything works as I like to.